# Assign ownership on a subfolder level

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

At the moment, we have different sites in Sharepoint for every department. However we want to transfer everything to one site for the entire company, and in that site have subfolders for every department instead. However one problem that I encounter with that is that at the moment, each department head are owners of their respective sites. This enables them to control their department site/folder and modify access and permissions for each document.

If we make one site however, and each department has their own subfolder. How can we assign them ownership of their subfolder, but not ownership of the entire site. Because we do not want the department head of IT to be able to go into HR and be able to see everything, or modify access.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You could give any permissions you want at the level site (i.e. Add all Department Heads into members group - **edit permissions**). Then in each folder you would need to break inheritance and give full control, for example, to the right Department Head.

See this link: [enter link description here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-permissions-on-a-subfolder-5427bd7c-f20a-4f75-8cf2-5359dd45a1a6)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will need to remove them from the **Site Collection Administrators** list if any, because a site collection administrator will have access to all contents in this site.

And then you can just break the inheritance of all subfolders and reassign permissions after they are transferred.
Reference here for SharePoint Online: [Change the permissions on a subfolder in SharePoint Online.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/change-the-permissions-on-a-subfolder-in/4dabccbe-044a-4f3e-b082-5b2dadcfbe25)

Answer (score 0):

Okay thanks for the responses. I have another question. I would like regular members to be able to manage access to the documents they have uploaded. So beside from the site owner who can manage access for everything from the entire site itself to specific documents or subfolders, I would also like the document owner to be able to manage access to the specific document he or she have uploaded.

Right now, only the site owner is able to manage access to the files. A document owner does not have the ability to manage access to the document uploaded. Is there some setting allowing this?

Comment: Hi @Crystalii, if you have further question on this thread, edit the original post with an update instead of writing as an Answer. It will bring confusion to others following or reading this thread.